# Protractor Shard execution - No Spec found

Tags: protractor, automated-tests

I didn't find much information online about this...

I changed my conf.js to be like this:

Inside my exports.config i have this

```
framework: 'jasmine2',
capabilities: {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  shardTestFiles: true,
  maxInstances: 2,
  chromeOptions: {
    args: [
          '--start-maximized'
          ]
 }
},

specs: ['./1_conf_summary.js', './2_conf_detail.js'],
```

I wanted to separate the specs, so I created more conf files with the scripts I want to execute, for example the 1_conf_summary.js contains:

```
suites: [
 './01_summary/summary_positive-spec.js'
],
```

*Also inside exports.config

but when I run the main conf.js, I get all the time this error:

```
[15:25:27] I/testLogger - [chrome #01-0] PID: 2348
[chrome #01-0] Specs: C:\Users\......\development_new_ui\1_conf_summary.js
[chrome #01-0]
[chrome #01-0] [15:25:25] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[chrome #01-0] Started
[chrome #01-0]
[chrome #01-0]
[chrome #01-0] No specs found
[chrome #01-0] Finished in 0.002 seconds
[chrome #01-0]

[15:25:27] I/testLogger -

[15:25:27] I/launcher - 1 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[15:25:27] I/testLogger -
```

I tried also with specs... but nothing works... any ideas how to solve this?

Thank you very much!!!!

*Edit*
Folder structure is:

```
Project folder
 |_01_summary
  |_summary_positive-spec.js
  |_summary_negative-spec.js
 |_other_specs
 |_lib
  |_functions and elements
 |Conf.js 
 |1_conf_summary.js
```

For the secondary conf files, I only have the suites (or the specs, tried with both), my main configuration is set in the main conf.js
Also tried directly with the specs to the main conf.js but then 1 script is executed twice instead of 2 different script executions

```
 exports.config = {
  suites: [
    './01_summary/summary_positive-spec.js'
  ],
 };
```

Comment: please sharing the `1_conf_summary.js` content

Comment: Do share your folder structure. The problem with the `path` to the `spec`

Comment: Hi @yong, edited as requested, not much inside the file tho (maybe this is the problem?)

Comment: Hi @Madhan, I added the structure as you asked

Comment: You can't specify `specs` as that,  Jamsine will load `'./1_conf_summary.js'` but this file didn't contain any `describe,  it`, So Jasmine can't find any test case.  Read this for how to config & use `suite` https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L270

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code line in your configurations.

```
 specs: ['./*.js'],
```

Comment: May be this also consider `config.js`